# Separating out key value pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In T-SQL how can one separate columns; one with the key and the other with the value for strings that follow the pattern below?

Examples of the strings that need to be processed are:

1. country_code: "US"province_name: "NY"city_name: "Old Chatham"
2. postal_code: "11746-8031"country_code: "US"province_name: "NY"street_address: "151 Millet Street North"city_name: "Dix Hills"
3. street_address: "1036 Main Street, Holbrook, NY 11741"

Desired outcome for example 1 would be:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| country_code | US |
| province_name | NY |
| city_name | Old Chatham |

Comment: Very close to JSON.  Are you missing a comma between the value and next key?   For example ...:"US" , province_name:"..."

Comment: I attempted to convert the string to json and then use the OPENJSON function to separate out the key value pair but was unsuccessful, as there isn't anything within the string to separate one key from another.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, no those are the exact strings. Unfortunately, that's the way the string is being formatted. my previous comment works if there is only one key. he only idea I can think of is to loop through each string with a UDF and insert a comma after every evenly indexed double quote... Then convert to json and use the OPENJSON function to do what I require.

Answer (score 5):

Nice to see Old Chatham ... a little touch of home

My first thought was to "correct" the JSON string, but that got risky.

Here is an option that will parse and pair the key/values

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cad643cd15b94b2846eaa841a143eb96)**

```
Select A.*
      ,C.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( replace(replace(replace(SomeCol,'"',':'),': :',':'),'::',':') ) ) B(CleanString)
 Cross Apply (
                Select [Key]  =max(case when Seq=1 then Val end)
                      ,[Value]=max(case when Seq=0 then Val end)
                 From (
                        Select Seq = row_number() over (order by [Key]) % 2
                              ,Grp = (row_number() over (order by [Key])-1) / 2
                              ,Val = Value
                         From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(string_escape(CleanString,'json'),':','","')+'"]' )
                         Where ltrim(Value)<>''
                      ) C1
                 Group By Grp
             ) C
```

**Results**

[image]